# about nested function unboundlocalerror in python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, nested

here is my function with 3 arguments of which two are with default values, and there is a nested function within this function.

```
def announce_highest(who=1, previous_high=0, previous_score=0):

assert who == 0 or who == 1, 'The who argument should indicate a player.'
# BEGIN PROBLEM 7
"*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
sentence = "That's the biggest gain yet for Player"
def say_highest(score0, score1):
    #nonlocal previous_score, previous_high
    print(who, previous_score)
    if who == 0:
        target = score0
    else:
        target = score1
    score_gap = target - previous_score
    if score_gap > previous_high:
        print(score_gap, "point" + 's' *(1 - (1 // score_gap)) + '!', sentence, who)
        previous_high = score_gap
    previous_score = target
    return announce_highest(who)
return say_highest
```

f0 = announce_highest() # Only announce Player 1 score gains
f1 = f0(11, 0)

When i do the assignment to f0, it runs ok. But when doing the assignment to f1, it raised a unboundlocal error:local variable 'previous_score' referenced before assignment. 
Why I do  something to the argument 'who'（such as print it）, it runs normally, but to the argument 'previous_high' and 'previous_score' with same operation, unboundlocal error……
why does this happen? Did not 'who' and 'previous_score' have the same scope?

Comment: I can get the desired effects partially with nonlocal statement, but I did not understand what the differences between the 'who' and 'previous_score'.  and I just want this function runs without any other side effect except printing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the professor John. This error is caused by the following assignment statement 'previous_score = target'. Once an assignment of "previous_score" exsits somewhere within the function defined in another function, the previous "previous_score" in the parent frame is no longer accessible.
That's why it raised an error.